# Cross context foreign key in EntityFramework core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to do a cross-context foreign key reference, but it's not working.

I have two DbContexts, `ApplicationDbContext` and `BankDbContext`. `ApplicationDbContext` has:

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

`BankDbContext` has:

```cs
public class AccountDbContext: DbContext
{
    public AccountDbContext(DbContextOptions<AccountDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

    public DbSet<AccountModel> Accounts { get; set; }
}
```

And the `AccountModel` has:

```cs
public class AccountModel
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public string AccountName { get; set; }

    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual IdentityUser User { get; set; }
}
```

`ApplicationDbContext` creates many tables; one of them is `AspNetUsers` (it saves the user details). When I update the table with the new migrations, it creates all the tables from `ApplicationDbContext` and `AccountModel` table, but for some reason, it also creates `IdentityUser` table. This shouldn't happen because `ApplicationDbContext` already creates one.

I tried adding `ForeignKey["AspNetUsers"]` attribute annotation on top of `public virtual IdentityUser User { get; set; }`, but it still creates that table.

the above code will work when I add `Accounts` DbSet to `ApplicationDbContext`, like this:

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
    public DbSet<AccountModel> Accounts { get; set; }
}
```

In a nutshell, I am trying to add a reference from one context to another on the same database, but it just creates duplicate tables with different names. Any help on this is appreciated.